# Remove pixels in image which is stored as array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have an numpy array `I` which stores `N` images of size `P` (number of pixels). Every image is of size `P = q*q`.

```
N = 1000 # number of images
q = 10 # length and width of image
P = q*q # pixels of image
I = np.ones((N,P)) # array with N images of size P
```

Now I want to delete patches of size `ps` around a selected index `IDX` (set all values to zero).

```
ps = 2 # patch size (ps x ps)
IDX = np.random.randint(0,P,(N,1))
```

My approach was to reshape every single image using `reshape(q,q)` and delete the pixels around `IDX`. Here I have the problem, that I do not know how to compute the position inside the image given `IDX`. Additionally I have to check if the index is not outside the image.

How to tackle this problem and is there any way to vectorize this procedure?

EDIT:

With the help of @Brenlla I did the following to remove patches. The problem with my approach is, that it needs three for-loops, and I have to reshape every image twice. Is there any way to increase the performance? This part slows down my code significantly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myplot(I):
    imgs = 10
    for i in range(imgs**2):
        plt.subplot(imgs,imgs,(i+1))
        plt.imshow(I[i].reshape(q,q), interpolation="none")
        plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()

N = 10000
q = 28
P = q*q
I = np.random.rand(N,P)

ps = 3
IDX = np.random.randint(0,P,(N,1))

for i in range(N):
    img = I[i].reshape(q,q)
    y0, x0 = np.unravel_index(IDX[i,0],(q,q))
    for x in range(ps):
        for y in range(ps):
            if (x0+x < q) and (y0+y < q):
                img[x0+x,y0+y] = 2.0
    I[i] = img.reshape(1,q*q)

myplot(I)
```

Comment: Before jumping to find a vectorized method, work on a loopy solution?

Comment: I tried that already but got stuck at the point where I have to find the coordinate (x,y) in the image given an index from IDX. I also omitted this problem and found, that it takes ages to do it this way.

Comment: To find the coordinate (x,y), you can just `np.unravel_index(IDX, (q,q))`

Comment: @Brenlla Great! I did not know that. I will try that and update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that can be done, but it involves heavy use of [np.broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Generate data plus a hard copy of `I`:

```
import time

N = 10000
q = 28
P = q*q
ps = 3 
I = np.random.rand(N,P)
IDX = np.random.randint(0,P,(N,1))
I_copy = I.copy()
```

And now run the loop solution. I switched `x0` and `y0`:

```
t0=time.clock()
for i in range(N):
    img = I[i].reshape(q,q)
    x0, y0 = np.unravel_index(IDX[i,0],(q,q))
    for x in range(ps):
        for y in range(ps):
            if (x0+x < q) and (y0+y < q):
                img[x0+x,y0+y] = 2.0
    I[i] = img.reshape(1,q*q)
print('With loop: {:.2f} ms'.format(time.clock()*1e3-t0*1e3))
```

Approx. 276 ms on my machine. Now the broadcasting:

```
t0 = time.clock()
x_shift, y_shift = np.meshgrid(range(ps), range(ps))
x, y = np.unravel_index(IDX, (q,q))
#roi for region of interest
roix = x[:,:,None]+x_shift; 
roiy = y[:,:,None]+y_shift;
roix[roix>q-1] = q-1; roiy[roiy>q-1] = q-1;
I_copy.reshape(N,q,q)[np.arange(N)[:, None, None], roix, roiy] = 2.0

print('No loop: {:.2f} ms'.format(time.clock()*1e3-t0*1e3))

print(np.array_equal(I, I_copy))
```

Roughly 80x faster